# Reporting missing dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf

Say there is a wpf-application, which uses different dlls. 
When the executable gets started, it loads the needed dlls as they are defined in the project's references.

When I now delete some of these dlls, the executable will crash showing the common dialog "... has stopped working" with the options close and debug the program. 
Similar to this one:[image]

This is not enough for me. I want my own dialog, showing some more information.

According to the debug output, there is a FileNotFoundException thrown in the App.Main() which is automatically generated. How can I handle this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the [`Application.DispatcherUnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) event.

When handling that event, you can give a custom message.

It is also possible to handle the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to catch assemblies that couldn't be loaded.

Comment: The exception is thrown in the App.Main() which is auto generated. To handle these exception, I need to set up event handlers in the method App.OnStartup(). But the exception occurs before the method OnStartUP() gets called. Can I handle these events somewhere else?